# Umlauts in PDF bookmarks printed wrong by hyperref

Tags: hyperref, luatex, bookmarks

Im using the the KOMA-Script documentclass `scrreprt` with luatex.

With the fontspec package the umlauts are printed correct in the chapters and sections but the hyperref package does print the umlauts wrong in the bookmarks of the pdf.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Ü}
\chapter{Test Ä}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: Umlauts in PDF bookmarks]

**How to print the bookmarks correct?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solution**

Use `\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}` in your preamble.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Ü}
\chapter{Test Ä}

\end{document}
```

**Explanation**

> The PDF format allows two encodings for bookmarks and entries in the
>   information dictionary: PDFDocEncoding and Unicode as UTF-16BE. Option
>   ”pdfencoding” selects between these encodings:
>
> - ”pdfdoc” uses PDFDocEncoding. It uses just one byte per character, but the supported characters are limited (244 in PDF-1.7).
> - ”unicode” sets Unicode. It is encoded as UTF-16BE. Two bytes are used for most characters, surrogates need four bytes.
> - ”auto” PDFDocEncoding if the string does not contain characters outside the encoding and Unicode otherwise.

**Credit**

[same topic discussed in german forum](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/11740/wie-bekommt-man-umlaute-in-den-bookmarks-von-hyperref-bei-verwendung-von-lualatex) and [hyperref package manual](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf)